# Quickest way to send a file from one computer to another in python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, file-transfer

I've tried multiple ways of sending files over a network from one computer to another with python 3.x but I would like to know which method is the most effective?

Comment: That's a very broad question! It could depend on the file size, the network reliability, the protocols available, the security requirements. The answer could be anything from using 2 Raspberry Pis with optical signalling to a truck-load of LTO tapes if it was 8 petabytes of data.

Comment: To put some limits to the question: File size won't be bigger than 10 TB, the environment between two regular home computers, lets say a macbook air and a regular windows laptop, and the security requirements is very high since the files could be very sensitive. The program I want to code will be both between computers on a LAN network and on WWW. So what would be industry standard for file sharing is basically the question.